# SD Card Not Recognized After System Sleep in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, suspend, 19.04, sd-card

On first boot of my computer (Ubuntu 19.04) SD cards work normally: When I insert one, the `/dev/mmcblk0` block auto-mounts to `/media/user`.

Sometimes I close the lid of my notebook and, consequently, the system goes to sleep. If afterwards I try to insert another SD card, it won't be recognized.

I think the relevant output of `lspci -v` is:

```
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at b1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

When it works, the output of `dmesg` when I insert an SD card is:

```
[43282.051646] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[43282.182783] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address aaaa
[43282.183467] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL08G 7.40 GiB 
[43282.186143]  mmcblk0: p1
[43282.660814] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[43282.661694] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[43282.706973] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

After system sleep, upon SD card insertion, `dmesg` outputs nothing.

What I've tried is removing and loading again the `rtsx_pci` driver with `modprobe` after system sleep, but to no avail. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction here?